# React dynamic table rows

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I have a react table that's mapping over an array of objects. I want to also map over one of the properties of those objects to create more rows. The object property I want to map over is also an array of objects. So my data look something like this:

```
[
  {id:1,name:"fakeName",children:[{id:10,name:"fakeChildName"}]},
  {id:2,name:"fakeName2",children:[{id:11,name:"fakeChildName11"}]}
]
```

Then, in my `render()`, I have this inside a table:

```
<tbody>
  {myArray.map(row => (
    <tr key={`row-${row.name}`}>
      <td>
        <div className="parent">{row.id}</div>
      </td>
      <td>{row.name}</td>
      <td />
      <td />
      <td />
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

This renders just fine. I want to iterate over the row.children objects to create more rows to fill up columns 3, 4, and 5 of that same table body. So I did this:

```
<tbody>
  {myArray.map(row => (
    <tr key={`row-${row.name}`}>
      <td>
        <div className="parent">{row.id}</div>
      </td>
      <td>{row.name}</td>
      <td />
      <td />
      <td />
    </tr>
    {row.children.map(childRow => (
      <tr key={`row-child-${childRow.name}`}>
        <td />
        <td />
        <td>{childRow.id}</td>
        <td>{childRow.name}</td>
        <td><button>myButton</button></td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  ))}
</tbody>
```

When I add that piece, I get an unexpected token error on the line where I have my `{row.children.map...` saying it's expecting a comma there. I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are closing the `<tr>` on the line before `{row.children.map...` which is illegal JSX. You can instead return an array of JSX:

```
{myArray.map(row => ([
  <tr key={`row-${row.name}`}>
    <td>
      <div className="parent">{row.id}</div>
    </td>
    <td>{row.name}</td>
    <td />
    <td />
    <td />
  </tr>,
  {...row.children.map(childRow => (
    <tr key={`row-child-${childRow.name}`}>
      <td />
      <td />
      <td>{childRow.id}</td>
      <td>{childRow.name}</td>
      <td><button>myButton</button></td>
    </tr>
  ))}
]))}
```

You can tell this makes things nasty, so I'd prefer clarity over brevity here:

```
{myArray.map(row => {
  const parentRow = (
    <tr key={`row-${row.name}`}>
      <td>
        <div className="parent">{row.id}</div>
      </td>
      <td>{row.name}</td>
      <td />
      <td />
      <td />
    </tr>
  );
  const childrenRows = row.children.map(childRow => (
    <tr key={`row-child-${childRow.name}`}>
      <td />
      <td />
      <td>{childRow.id}</td>
      <td>{childRow.name}</td>
      <td><button>myButton</button></td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return [parentRow, ...childrenRows];
})}
```

Comment: Thank you. I chose to use your second example.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a [single React element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render).

Try this (`div` is the single React element):

```
<tbody>
  {myArray.map(row => {
    return (
      <div>
        <tr key={`row-${row.name}`}>
          <td>
            <div className="parent">{row.id}</div>
          </td>
          <td>{row.name}</td>
          <td />
          <td />
          <td />
        </tr>
        {row.children.map(childRow => (
          <tr key={`row-child-${childRow.name}`}>
            <td />
            <td />
            <td>{childRow.id}</td>
            <td>{childRow.name}</td>
            <td><button>myButton</button></td>
           </tr>
         ))}
       </div>
     )
    })}
  </tbody>
```